# Writing a recursive function

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to write a recursive function in Python to count the number of pairs of repeated characters in a string. Example: "hellmoo" = 2
To get me started, I first tried to write an iterative version of the program. Here's my attempt:

```
counter = 0
string = input("Enter string:" )

for i in range(len(string)-1):
    if string[i] == string[i+1]:
        counter = counter+1


print (counter)
```

Now, I do not understand how I can write a recursive function from the above iterative program. I have tried to think of my base case as:

```
if string == "":
   return (0)
```

I'm not sure if I am correct there. Could someone please help me do this? Thanks!

Comment: What do you return for `count("aaaa")` ?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that assume pairs of characters do not overlap

Comment: Basically, you should return 0 if you iterated the whole string, if not, check the current char and the next one, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

your logic assuming two characters in the string, so I think you need two base cases, for empty string and for one character string. (or one base case for string shorter then 2)

maybe something like this:

```
def count_doubles(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return 0
    else:
        if string[0] == string[1]:
            return count_doubles(string[1:]) + 1
        else:
            return count_doubles(string[1:])

>>> count_doubles("hellmoo")
2
```

p.s.
I don't know why you want to do this with recursion, I dont think it's good idea for this task.
a more pythonic way to do it can be:

```
>>> string = "hellmoo"
>>> len(filter(lambda x:x[0]==x[1],zip(string[1:],string[:-1])))
2
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. This is similar to what I was looking for. However, when I try to run this code, there is no output - just blank. It should count the repeated pairs of characters in the string. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @john what exactly did you try to run (show your code), this function gets a string and return integer.

Comment: `def count_doubles(string):
    if len(string) < 2:
        return 0
    else:
        if string[0] == string[1]:
            return count_doubles(string[1:]) + 1
        else:
            return count_doubles(string[1:])
        
count_doubles("hello")`

I wonder if I have done the right thing

Comment: This is the function, I meant, what is your code that call this function? I updated the answer to make it more clear

Comment: @Elisha my code that calls this function is at the end of my previous comment. This is similar to how you have called the function

Comment: it works for me, I guess you are doing something wrong, maybe your indentations.

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of a silly assignment for Python, but in other languages that use a different fundamental data type, like a cons-list instead of an array, it makes sense.

You know how to write `counter` for a 2-element string.

For a 3-element string, you do the 2-element count on `s[:2]`, then you do the 2-element count on `s[1:]`.

For a 4-element string, you do the 2-element count on `s[:2]`, then you do the 3-element count on `s[1:]`.

For an N-element string, you do the 2-element count on `s[:2]`, then you do the N-1-element count on `s[1:]`.

Of course that leaves out the 0-element and 1-element cases, but you can just add 2 more base cases for that.

Answer (score 0):

Defining a basic recursion with a wrapper:

```
def recursion(str, idx):
    if (idx + 1 == len(str)):
        return 0
    if (str[idx+1] == str[idx]):
        return 1 + recursion(str, idx + 1)
    return recursion(str, idx + 1)

def count(str):
    if len(str) == 0:
        return 0
    return recursion(str, 0)

>>> count("hellmoo")
2
>>> count("hellbb")
2
>>> count("hellbbvv")
3
>>> count("hh")
1
>>> count("")
0
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was looking for something with a single function. Is that possible?

Comment: Define the recursion inside count